# JQ: filter and select rows from JSONL input?

Tags: json, select, jq

Suppose I have a JSONL file:

```
# foo.jsonl

{ "arbitrary.key":"foo" }
{ "arbitrary.key":"foobar" }
{ "arbitrary.key":"bar" }
```

And I would like to filter the rows of this file:

```
# in pseudo code
cat foo.jsonl | jq '. | where(."arbitrary.key" | is_match("^foo"))'
```

Is this possible in `jq`?

Comment: Since is_match is your own invention, it would be helpful if you could be explicit about whether you require the value of .key to start with "foo".

Answer (score 2):

Got it, posting because this took a few minutes and there were some red-herrings in the first few threads I followed:

```
cat foo.jsonl | jq '. | select( ."arbitrary.key" | match("^f"))'
```

Comment: It can be written simpler: `cat doc.jsonl | jq 'select(.key | test("^foo.*"))'`

Comment: Note that I used `^`, otherwise the pattern will match any key containing `foo` substring (e.g., 'barfoobaz')

Comment: no need for `.*` in the regex in this case `^foo` will suffice

Comment: @un.def is test more complex because it is more semantically ambiguous?